problema con un codigo en JAVA
Estoy haciendo una aplicación y estoy utilizando pestañas(jTabbedPane)  funciona asi: presiono tres botones (botón a, boto b y botón 3) y me sale las tres pestaña en el orden que presione y se muestra el contenido de la ultima pestaña que abrir, ahora si yo cierro las pestaña pestaña3 se quita y me muestra el contenido de la pestaña2 y si cierro la pestaña 2 me muestra el contenido de la pestaña1 y si cierro me muestra con contenido por defecto (cerré atrás hacia adelante), eso si me funciona. El problema:  es al momento de cerrar  si cierro la pestaña en cualquier orden  se buguea si cierro la pestaña 1 me muestra la pestaña2 pero con el contenido de la pestaña 1 y los otros contenido ya no me sale espero que me puedan ayudar  contacto: yanezp006@gmail.com si desean el codigo completo
private void agregarPestañaConCierre(String titulo, JPanel contenido) {
// Verificar si la pestaña ya está abierta
    int index = jTabbedPane1_pestañas.indexOfTab(titulo);
    if (index != -1) {
        jTabbedPane1_pestañas.setSelectedIndex(index);
        cargarContenidoEnPanel3(contenido); // Cargar contenido existente
        return;
    }

    // Agregar una nueva pestaña con un panel vacío
    JPanel emptyPanel = new JPanel();
    jTabbedPane1_pestañas.addTab(titulo, emptyPanel);
    int tabIndex = jTabbedPane1_pestañas.indexOfComponent(emptyPanel);

    pestañasContenidos.put(tabIndex, contenido); // Asociar el índice de la pestaña con su contenido

    // Crear el panel de la pestaña con un botón de cierre
    JPanel panelTab = new JPanel(new java.awt.FlowLayout(java.awt.FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));
    panelTab.setOpaque(false);
    javax.swing.JLabel labelTitulo = new javax.swing.JLabel(titulo);
    panelTab.add(labelTitulo);

    javax.swing.JButton botonCerrar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    botonCerrar.setBorder(null);
    botonCerrar.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    botonCerrar.setFocusable(false);

    java.net.URL imgURLNormal = getClass().getResource("/imagenes/X.png");
    java.net.URL imgURLHover = getClass().getResource("/imagenes/X_selec.png");

    if (imgURLNormal != null && imgURLHover != null) {
        botonCerrar.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(imgURLNormal));
        botonCerrar.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                botonCerrar.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(imgURLHover));
            }
            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                botonCerrar.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(imgURLNormal));
            }
        });
    } else {
        System.err.println("No se encontraron las imágenes de cierre.");
    }

    // Listener para el botón de cierre de pestañas
    botonCerrar.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) -> {
        int closeTabIndex = jTabbedPane1_pestañas.indexOfTabComponent(panelTab);
        if (closeTabIndex != -1) {
            jTabbedPane1_pestañas.remove(closeTabIndex);
            pestañasContenidos.remove(closeTabIndex); // Elimina el contenido asociado

            // Verificar el índice de la pestaña actualmente seleccionada
            int selectedIndex = jTabbedPane1_pestañas.getSelectedIndex();
            if (selectedIndex != -1) {
                JPanel panel = pestañasContenidos.get(selectedIndex);
                cargarContenidoEnPanel3(panel != null ? panel : new JPanel());
            } else {
                cargarContenidoEnPanel3(contenidoInicial.getMainPanel()); // Restaurar el contenido inicial si no hay pestañas
            }
        }
    });

    panelTab.add(botonCerrar);
    jTabbedPane1_pestañas.setTabComponentAt(tabIndex, panelTab);
    jTabbedPane1_pestañas.setSelectedIndex(tabIndex);

    // Cargar el contenido de la pestaña recién creada en jPanel3
    cargarContenidoEnPanel3(contenido);

    // Agregar un ChangeListener al JTabbedPane para actualizar el contenido de jPanel3 al cambiar de pestaña
    jTabbedPane1_pestañas.addChangeListener(e -> {
        int selectedIndex = jTabbedPane1_pestañas.getSelectedIndex();
        if (selectedIndex != -1) {
            JPanel panel = pestañasContenidos.get(selectedIndex);
            cargarContenidoEnPanel3(panel != null ? panel : new JPanel());
        } else {
            cargarContenidoEnPanel3(contenidoInicial.getMainPanel());
        }
    });
}


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Esto no es una red social. No va tu contacto en la pregunta, los bots que recopilan mails te agradecen haberlo agregado, pero aqui nadie te va a escribir un mail.. toda la info debe estar en la pregunta...

Hola Andres, bienvenido, es un poco difícil saber que pasa, ya que el código que muestras tiene muchas lagunas, el problema es que el método borrar no quita la pestaña que tu crees que quita, y creo que el error esta en la siguiente linea: int closeTabIndex = jTabbedPane1_pestañas.indexOfTabComponent( panelTab ); esta debería ser: int closeTabIndex = jTabbedPane1_pestañas.getSelectedIndex();.

Buenas, Andrés, no necesitamos todo tu código, debes intentar editar tu pregunta de forma que haya un ejemplo mínimo reproducible. En tu caso sería un pequeño programa java que cree un JFrame y que añada y elimine los tabs usando el código que has incluido originalmente. De forma que nosotros podamos copiarlo en nuestro IDE y "jugar" un poco con él para encontrar el fallo.

Hacer ese "ejercicio" de simplificación y reducción también puede ayudarte a ti para resolver el problema por ti mismo, ya que elimina todo el código que no está directamente relacionado con el problema, de forma que no te "distrae".
